How to Sync Two Boot Nodes for Redundancy?
I'm working on a blockchain project and want to ensure uninterrupted block production even if one of our boot nodes goes down. How can we effectively sync two boot nodes so that if one goes offline, the other can seamlessly take over block generation duties?


The best would be if bootnodes and collators/validators are different nodes.

There is no failover mechanism. The best would be that you register multiple validators/collators from the beginning. If anyone of them goes down, the other one can continue producing blocks.


